# Qt SQL Pattern Matching

Tags: c++, mysql, sql-server, qt, uitableview

I am working on a C++ Qt program where I include a mysql database.

I want to do some sql queries and show the output on a tableview. Because I also want to filter the results I wrote this kind of code snippet:

```
query->prepare("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contactsName LIKE '%:name%';");
query->bindValue(":name", mUi->searchContactsLine->text());
query->exec();

mModel->setQuery(*query);

mUi->tableContacts->setModel(mModel);
```

... where

> searchContactsLine

is the inputlinebox to search for a string,

> mModel

is my QSqlQueryModel and

> tableContacts

is my TableView in qt.

As you can see I want to use pattern matching with the dollar sign. But if I run the program I got no row back.. no matter what I am searching for.
In the past I had problems with the inverted commas ('...') while using the bindValue function, but if I delete it from the sql command I get an sql syntax error.

So what do I wrong? Maybe you have an idea of that.

Comment: Try to add the '%' to the parameter, e.g. `bindValue(":name", '%'+mUi->searchContactsLine->text()+'%'` and just `LIKE :name;` in the query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111130/qt-qsqlquery-prepare-and-bindvalue-not-working?rq=1

Comment: @Solarflare thats what I am searching for! Thanks